# I clicked on my color button images but they are not appearing in an array in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, click

I'm using Chrome developer to test out the 4 color buttons I created. Every time I click on a button I should be building up an array in console, but its not doing everything. Is my syntax wrong?

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];

$('.btn').click(function(){
  var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
});

function nextSequence(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4);
  var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);
}
```

Comment: Please update to include the html. Also, when do you call the nextSequence function?

Comment: try adding nextSequence() into your click event to call the function. Also if you do a console.log('hi') in the click event, does it log 'hi' to the console?

Comment: **Is my syntax wrong?** - Yes, your syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen, that your script is called before the browser finishes DOM construction. In this case your script can not find any buttons with class 'btn' in the DOM. You have to call your script after terminating the DOM construction:
`$(document).ready(function() { 'your code' });`